# how to do json_decode of json_encode

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to use json_decode to combine a few json objects.. i need to retrieve database values based on album id,. but i couldn't it,.

can anyone tell me where i ve committed mistake?

```
$album_ids_id = array("album_ids"=>array(2,4,5));
// $album_ids = $_REQUEST['alb_id'];

$album_ids = json_encode($album_ids_id);

$id_list_array = json_decode($album_ids,true);

$id_array = $id_list_array->album_ids;

var_dump($id_list_array);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($id_array);$i++)
  {

    $alb_id = $id_array[$i]->alb_id;


    $album_sel_query = "SELECT a.a_id as id,a.a_name as name,round((b.total_value/b.total_votes),1) as rating,b.total_votes,b.total_value,a.a_pic as image,c.b_name FROM _album a inner join ratings b on b.id=a.a_id INNER JOIN _band c on c.b_id=a.b_id where a.a_id='".$alb_id."' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($album_sel_query);
    if (!$result)
      die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0)
      {

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $alb_name =$data['name']; 

            $singer = $data['b_name'];

            $rating = $data['rating'];

            $rate_value = $data['total_value'];

            $rate_votes = $data['total_votes'];

            $alb_pic =$data['image']; 
            $resmsg[] = array("Album_id"=>$alb_id,"Album_name"=>$alb_name,"Album_singer"=>$singer,"Album_rating"=>$rating,"Rating_total_value"=>$rate_value,"Rating_total_votes"=>$rate_votes,"Album_image_name"=>$alb_pic);

          }

        $jsonarr = array("response"=>array("success"=>"Y","ALBUM_DETAILS"=>$resmsg));
      }
    else
      {
        $jsonarr = array("response"=>array("success"=>"N","ALBUM_DETAILS"=>"Data not found"));
      }
  }
echo json_encode($jsonarr);
```

since i'd used var_dump(),. the output shows that

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["album_ids"]=> array(1) { ["alb_id"]=> string(1) "5" } } } {"response":{"success":"N","ALBUM_DETAILS":"Data not found"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with json. The error is in the first line. You use three times the same key, but array keys are unique.

```
array("alb_id"=>"2","alb_id"=>"4","alb_id"=>"5");
```

Must be :

```
array(2, 4, 5);
```

Comment: thank u,. i got proper array format,. but still prob in retrieving database value

Answer (score 1):

First, this isn't valid:

```
$album_ids_id = array("album_ids"=>array("alb_id"=>"2","alb_id"=>"4","alb_id"=>"5"));
```

A key in an array can only have one value, you can't have multiple `alb_id` keys in the same array. It should be:

```
$album_ids_id = array("album_ids"=>array(2, 4, 5));
```

Second, since you're giving the `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()`, it return associative arrays, not objects. So

```
$id_array[] = $id_list_array->album_ids;
```

should be:

```
$id_array = $id_list_array['album_ids'];
```

Also notice that there should not be a `[]` at the end of `$id_array` -- that's only used when you want to push a new element onto an array, not when you're assigning the array variable itself.

Then change your `for` loop to :

```
foreach ($id_array as $alb_id) {
```

and get rid of the `$alb_id` assignment inside the loop.

Comment: some prob in my foreach ????

Comment: I don't know, is there?

Comment: ya if i use foreach it doesn't takes value..

Comment: I don't know what "doesn't take value" means. If you fixed the other problems in your array assignment, `$id_array` should be an array of numbers, and `foreach` should iterate over them -- it's basic PHP syntax.